# Syntax error in xpath in selenium code in python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, datepicker, syntax-error

I am trying to select the date using Selenium in Python. The HTML code looks as below:
[image]

For selecting a date, I am using following code:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import WebElement

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\cssaxena\Cardboard\chromedriver.exe")
url = 'https://cardboard.aka.amnz.com/#/businessGroups?app=$0c58c79c8a3280f4e953da2206007a9592499252-0'
driver.get(url)

WebElement dateBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@name='daterange']"));

dateBox.sendKeys("20 Mar 2020, 12 AM - 03 Apr 2020, 11 PM");
```

and getting following error:

```
  File "C:/Users/cssaxena/Cardboard.py", line 15
    WebElement dateBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@name='daterange']");
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the java selenium.

Replace

```
WebElement dateBox = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@name='daterange']"));
```

With

```
dateBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@name='daterange']")
```

Also Noticed that you're using the following

```
dateBox.sendKeys("20 Mar 2020, 12 AM - 03 Apr 2020, 11 PM");
```

Which is also the java selenium, replace with the line below

```
dateBox.send_keys("20 Mar 2020, 12 AM - 03 Apr 2020, 11 PM");
```

Full Script

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import WebElement

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\cssaxena\Cardboard\chromedriver.exe")
url = 'https://cardboard.aka.amnz.com/#/businessGroups? 
app=$0c58c79c8a3280f4e953da2206007a9592499252-0'
driver.get(url)

dateBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@name='daterange']")
dateBox.send_keys("20 Mar 2020, 12 AM - 03 Apr 2020, 11 PM");
```

Comment: Hi Davis, that bit got fixed. But I am still getting following error:
```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@name='daterange']"}
```

Comment: Sometimes elements load after the initial page load so I suggest you import time at the top and after your driver.get(url) line you do time.sleep(5)

Comment: Thanks David for the response. I guess I can't pass date like that as I am getting ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable. Can you help in passing the date on the basis of HTML code shared. (Have shared the detailed HTML in question)

Comment: You can't interact with a division. To be able to .send_keys it should be an input type. You would have to provide a website link for further help.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a Java line of code you tried to copy in to a Python script. Python is a dynamically typed language, and you don't declare the type of a variable. Just lose the `WebElement` and you should be OK:

```py
dateBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@name='daterange']");
```